# Carousel Effect in React with Styled Components Won't Listen For Media Queries

Tags: reactjs, carousel, styled-components

I am trying to make this component change from a carousel to a display: flex where the projects and laid out above another (for mobile).

I have attempted a few things but keep having issues with the refs. I have tried to use innerRef and that didn't seem to solve the issue.

Here is the github: https://github.com/rafawelsh/portfolio2/blob/master/src/components/Projects/Projects.js

Here is the live site: https://rafawelsh.github.io/portfolio2/

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

// dynamically setting the height of the outermost container
const TallContainer = styled.div.attrs(({ dynamicHeight }) => ({
  style: { height: `${dynamicHeight}px` },
}))`
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: var(--baseColor);
`;

// middle container sustaining the wide horizontal
const StickyContainer = styled.div`
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
`;

const HorizontalScroll = styled.div.attrs(({ translateX }) => ({
  style: { transform: `translateX(${translateX}px)` },
}))`
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    will-change: transform;
`;

const calcDynamicHeight = (objectWidth) => {
  const vw = window.innerWidth;
  const vh = window.innerHeight;
  return objectWidth - vw + vh;
};

const handleDynamicHeight = (ref, setDynamicHeight) => {
  const objectWidth = ref.current.scrollWidth;
  const dynamicHeight = calcDynamicHeight(objectWidth);
  setDynamicHeight(dynamicHeight);
};

const applyScrollListener = (ref, setTranslateX) => {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const offsetTop = -ref.current.offsetTop;
    setTranslateX(offsetTop);
  });
};

function Projects({ children }) {
  const [dynamicHeight, setDynamicHeight] = useState(null);
  const [translateX, setTranslateX] = useState(0);

  const containerRef = useRef(null);
  const objectRef = useRef(null);

  const resizedHandler = () => {
    handleDynamicHeight(objectRef, setDynamicHeight);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    handleDynamicHeight(objectRef, setDynamicHeight);
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizedHandler);
    applyScrollListener(containerRef, setTranslateX);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='projects'>
      <TallContainer dynamicHeight={dynamicHeight} className='tallContainer'>
        <StickyContainer ref={containerRef} className='stickyContainer'>
          <HorizontalScroll
            translateX={translateX}
            ref={objectRef}
            className='horizontalScroll'
          >
            {children}
          </HorizontalScroll>
        </StickyContainer>
      </TallContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Projects;
```